# Boot Order Device Priority In BIOS

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, usb-flash-drive, thinkpad

I am using Lenevo ThinkPad E 570.                                             I can enter into BIOS.                                                        I would like to change Boot Order Priority to USB from BIOS.                 How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following way:

1. Plug in the USB device.
2. Press **F12** during computer startup.
3. We can see **USB HDD**, we find U device cannot be started with this option, because the BIOS disables the USB device boot.
4. Press the TAB key to switch the **APP menu**, then select **Setup** to enter the BIOS.
5. Find **Security** in **BIOS**.
6. Find **Secure Boot** in **Security**, then disable **Secure Boot**.
7. Select “**Startup**” next to **Security**.
8. Find **UEFI/Legacy Boot** in **Startup**, set **UEFI/Legacy Boot->Legacy only** and **CSM support->Yes**, then find **Boot**, click **Enter**.
9. Find **USB HDD** in **Boot**, adjust **USB HDD** in the first one through the up and down arrow keys and plus and minus keys in keyboard, then save the **BIOS** settings by clicking **F10**.
10. Restart the computer to see if it starts from USB device.